# Remove unknown ata password with hdparm

Tags: linux, passwords, hdparm, ata

I received 2 320Gb 2.5" harddrives, Toshiba  Model Number: MQ01AB032 and Western Digital Model Number: WDC WD3200BPVT-35ZEST0. Both have the same hdparm Security output which I obtained by running `sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdb`

```
Security:
Master password revision code = 1
        supported
        enabled
        locked
not     frozen
not     expired: security count
        supported: enhanced erase
Security level high
76min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 76min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
```

It shows that password is enabled and the drives are locked. I have tried various hdparm commands and all give me this output. `SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 40 01 21 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`

From this command:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo hdparm --user-master u --security-erase NULL /dev/sdb 
security_password: ""

/dev/sdb:
 Issuing SECURITY_ERASE command, password="", user=user
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 40 01 21 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

I have tried `sudo hdparm --user-master m --security-erase NULL /dev/sdb` as the master, that results in the same output.

```
sudo hdparm --user-master m --security-erase NULL /dev/sdb         
security_password: ""

/dev/sdb:
 Issuing SECURITY_ERASE command, password="", user=master
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 40 01 21 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
PS. The data isnt important at all, if the drive needs to be nuked, that's fine, I just need to be able to use the drives.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try `--security-disable`. How are the drives connected to the computer?

Comment: I inserted the hard drive into the netbook after the ubuntu 18.04 live cd had booted. the is the output of sudo hdparm --user-master u --security-disable NULL :  sudo hdparm --user-master u --security-disable NULL /dev/sdb
security_password: ""

/dev/sdb:
 Issuing SECURITY_DISABLE command, password="", user=user
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 40 01 21 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 40 01 21 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Comment: Try this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/502664/why-is-secure-erase-not-working-sg-io-bad-missing-sense-data

Comment: The hard drive is not frozen, suspended the pc and issued this command: sudo ./hdparm --user-master u --security-disable "" /dev/sdb
security_password: ""

/dev/sdb:
 Issuing SECURITY_DISABLE command, password="", user=user
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 40 00 21 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 40 00 21 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Comment: SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 40 00 21 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00. Seems to be consistent no matter which security command I issue.